# spring model object is not rending on jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am facing problem while creating `spring` `mvc` project, my `JSP` page is not rendered as expected below is code

my controller is

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){

        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        model.addObject("msg","hello page");
        return model;

    }


}
```

jsp page is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> {$msg}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**below is output**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it, but you have a typo here:

```
<h2> {$msg}</h2>
```

Spring uses `${nameOfAttr}` to refer bean/model attributes, so... you must write:

```
<h2> ${msg}</h2>
```

And your message will display as expected. For further info please [check this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm)

Comment: glad to hear... :) that happens all time, fresh eyes usually help more than great knowledge